# Query sys.x$session is slow

Tags: mysql

I am facing an issue with a slow query on sys.x$session

Below is my query statement:

```
select * from sys.x$session;
```

This query takes about 1.5 seconds, but `SHOW processlist` is very fast.

Why would `x$session` take more time to complete?
Can anyone please explain the cause?

Attach this MySQL(5.7.23) performance schema variables and values.

```
Variable_name  Value
performance_schema  ON
performance_schema_accounts_size  -1
performance_schema_digests_size  10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_stages_history_size  10
performance_schema_events_statements_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_statements_history_size  10
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_transactions_history_size  10
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size  10000
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size  10
performance_schema_hosts_size  -1
performance_schema_max_cond_classes  80
performance_schema_max_cond_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_digest_length  1024
performance_schema_max_file_classes  80
performance_schema_max_file_handles  32768
performance_schema_max_file_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_index_stat  -1
performance_schema_max_memory_classes  320
performance_schema_max_metadata_locks  -1
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes  210
performance_schema_max_mutex_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_prepared_statements_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_program_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_rwlock_classes  40
performance_schema_max_rwlock_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_socket_classes  10
performance_schema_max_socket_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_sql_text_length  1024
performance_schema_max_stage_classes  150
performance_schema_max_statement_classes  193
performance_schema_max_statement_stack  10
performance_schema_max_table_handles  -1
performance_schema_max_table_instances  -1
performance_schema_max_table_lock_stat  -1
performance_schema_max_thread_classes  50
performance_schema_max_thread_instances  -1
performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_size  512
performance_schema_setup_actors_size  -1
performance_schema_setup_objects_size  -1
performance_schema_users_size  -1
```

```
CREATE SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `sys`.`x$session` AS select `x$processlist`.`thd_id` AS `thd_id`,`x$processlist`.`conn_id` AS `conn_id`,`x$processlist`.`user` AS `user`,`x$processlist`.`db` AS `db`,`x$processlist`.`command` AS `command`,`x$processlist`.`state` AS `state`,`x$processlist`.`time` AS `time`,`x$processlist`.`current_statement` AS `current_statement`,`x$processlist`.`statement_latency` AS `statement_latency`,`x$processlist`.`progress` AS `progress`,`x$processlist`.`lock_latency` AS `lock_latency`,`x$processlist`.`rows_examined` AS `rows_examined`,`x$processlist`.`rows_sent` AS `rows_sent`,`x$processlist`.`rows_affected` AS `rows_affected`,`x$processlist`.`tmp_tables` AS `tmp_tables`,`x$processlist`.`tmp_disk_tables` AS `tmp_disk_tables`,`x$processlist`.`full_scan` AS `full_scan`,`x$processlist`.`last_statement` AS `last_statement`,`x$processlist`.`last_statement_latency` AS `last_statement_latency`,`x$processlist`.`current_memory` AS `current_memory`,`x$processlist`.`last_wait` AS `last_wait`,`x$processlist`.`last_wait_latency` AS `last_wait_latency`,`x$processlist`.`source` AS `source`,`x$processlist`.`trx_latency` AS `trx_latency`,`x$processlist`.`trx_state` AS `trx_state`,`x$processlist`.`trx_autocommit` AS `trx_autocommit`,`x$processlist`.`pid` AS `pid`,`x$processlist`.`program_name` AS `program_name` from `sys`.`x$processlist` where ((`x$processlist`.`conn_id` is not null) and (`x$processlist`.`command` <> 'Daemon'))
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE VIEW sys.x$session`

Comment: Ditto for each table that that VIEW references.  It's a nihtmare of stuff.  I wonder if 8.0 speeds it up.

Comment: I had attached the sys.x$session schema

Comment: Please file a bug with bugs.mysql.com (if there is not already one); this is an unconscionable performance degradation.